# How to check if email textbox contains a name from name textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an aspx page and two textbox and a button on it.I want to check if email contains name after pushing the button.I guess i can do it with CustomValidator,but i dont know how.How can i do it ?

Comment: What do you mean contains name do you mean check if the email textbox is Empty or not..?

Comment: If emails contains *which* name? There are a lot of tutorials for the CustomValidator, for example http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/

Comment: no,if i write 'Tom' in name textbox,my email has to be,for example,tom123@abc.com ... i mean email has to have my name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var exists = $("#txtName").val().indexOf($("#txtName").attr("name")) >= 0
```

or pure JS:

```
var exists = document.getElementById('txtName').value.indexOf(document.getElementById('txtName').attributes["name"]) >= 0
```

Comment: thank you,i used CustomValidator on the asp side,and on the javascript side i used your code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a message popup before it sends the information to the server, use Javascript to validate the textbox, on the server side it should check if there is a value as well.

Don't try to validate much on the textbox, as there are a lot of specialized rules for email addresses, at most just check for a letter, the "@" and a "."

Answer (score 0):

Just check in your button click event handler if the name is contained in the email adress. For example, the following if-statement would do the trick:

```
public void button1_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBoxEmail.Text.ToUpper().IndexOf(textBoxName.Text.ToUpper()) >= 0)
       /* continue with processing */
    else
       /* display an error */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this after you click the Button on the Button ClickEvent
do something like this Check to see if textbox.Contains('@');

```
var HasValid = checkText.Contains('@');
```

returns true or false;

but there are also other potential things you need to check for what about if the individual types
  Thomas@
  Thomas@yahoo
  Thomas@yahoo.
  etc

You should probably look at using a RegEx Expression to check otherwise you will have to utilize some other mechanism to check ValidEmail[RegEx Email Pattern](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx)

or
[RegEx Valid Email](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

here is an even better example and explanation I hope that you can follow this simple code..

At the start of the program you will have to call the required namespace like so:
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Then in your code the first thing to do is to define the string which you think might be an email address:

```
string _address = "Thomas@someemailaddress.com";
Regex emailregex = new Regex("(?<user>[^@]+)@(?<host>.+)");
```

The following line creates a Regular Expression object called emailregex. This class takes an expression in it's constructor as shown above. Note that it is also possible to do sub-string capturing using the  syntax. These substrings are then available in the m.Groups array (for example m.Groups["user"] and m.Groups["host"].

So moving on, the next stage is to create a Match object, which we can use to tell whether or not the regular expression was matcyhed. The match object is set by calling the Match method on the expression and passing in the address.

```
Match m = emailregex.Match(_address);
```

from that point, you can then test the result with a simple conditional statement:

```
if ( m.Success ) 
{
   // success,, so do something;
}else
{
   // didn't manage to find the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check using following two `txtEmail.Text.Contains(txtName.Text)` or `txtEmailText.IndexOf(txtName.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;`